# Why new object is keep being undefined?

Tags: javascript, object, dom-events

**Why  my object `newEmp` is not defined?**

I'm trying to create this "Employee Management System".

On click of the <kbd>Add New Employee</kbd> button there's an `EventListener` which invokes
`addNew()`.

`addNew()` does this:

1. `e.preventDefault()`.
2. takes the values of the form inputs.
3. assigning them into a new object - `newEmp` through `Employee()` Constructor
   function.

When finished I check the value of my new Object - `newEmp`
and the console tells me:

> "newEmp is not defined".

*js file:*

```
//Form HTML Elements
var empName = document.getElementById("emp-name");
var empSkill = document.getElementById("emp-skill");
var empTitle = document.getElementById("emp-title");
var addNewEmp = document.getElementById("btn-add-new-emp");

//Event Listener - add new employee
addNewEmp.addEventListener("click", addNew);


//Adding new Employee
function addNew(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // 1. Create "newEmp" Object based on newEmployee constructor function
    // 2. Assign the inputs.values inside the "newEmp" Object

    empName = empName.value;
    empSkill = empSkill.value;
    empTitle = empTitle.value;

    var newEmp = new Employee(empName, empSkill, empTitle);
    console.log(newEmp);

    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
    return newEmp;
}

//New Employee  -  Constructor function
function Employee(name, skill, title) {
    this.name = name;
    this.skill = skill;
    this.title = title;
}
```

*html file:*

```
<section id="addNewEmployee">
    <h2>Employee Management System</h2>
    <form action="" id="myForm">
        <input type="text" id="emp-name" placeholder="Employee Name...">
        <input type="text" id="emp-skill" placeholder="Employee Skill...">

        <select name="title" id="emp-title">
            <option value="developer">Developer</option>
            <option value="seo">SEO</option>
            <option value="teacher">Teacher</option>
            <option value="designer">Designer</option>
        </select>

        <button id="btn-add-new-emp">Add New Employee</button>
    </form>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your example on jsfiddle and it worked for me, I got console output:

`Employee {name: "name", skill: "skill", title: "developer"}`

Must be something else causing that:

https://jsfiddle.net/1p1ym3pv/

Comment: Its mistakening. in the function there's a console.log command that print it to the console.
but try in console to get the value of newEmp and it will give you newEmp not defined

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem.
newEmp should be first assign globaly, and not localy inside a function,
so when I try to return a new value back from the function it will have a place to save the new info.

```
//Form HTML Elements
var empName = document.getElementById("emp-name");
var empSkill = document.getElementById("emp-skill");
var empTitle = document.getElementById("emp-title");
var addNewEmp = document.getElementById("btn-add-new-emp");

// New Empoyee Object
var newEmp = {};

//Event Listener - add new employee
addNewEmp.addEventListener("click", addNew);


//Adding new Employee
function addNew(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // 1. Create "newEmp" Object based on newEmployee constructor function
    // 2. Assign the inputs.values inside the "newEmp" Object

    empName = empName.value;
    empSkill = empSkill.value;
    empTitle = empTitle.value;


    newEmp = new Employee(empName, empSkill, empTitle);

    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
    return newEmp;
}

//New Employee  -  Constructor function
function Employee(name, skill, title) {
    this.name = name;
    this.skill = skill;
    this.title = title;
}
```